# Looking for a css property

Tags: css, html

I saw this site :http://www.leeroy.ca/ and I would love to know how they make the interaction on the first page can someone give me a hint thanks!

Comment: They're using [ParticleSlider](http://particleslider.com/) just a heads up though, this question will probably get downvoted/closed as this is not really the type of question that SO is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using Canvas. The plugin they have used is called [ParticleSlider](http://particleslider.com/). This is a commercial plugin, which needs licence to use, and it can be initialized using the following code:

```
// Create a new Particle
var ps = new ParticleSlider();
var ptl = new ps.Particle(ps);
```

Or the other one is:

```
// Create a 100px wide ParticleSlider.
var ps = new ParticleSlider({
    width: 100
});
// Create a ParticleSlider with default width
// and change width to 100px.
var ps = new ParticleSlider();
ps.width = 100;
```